# Excel VBA : How to pass parameter to Power query GET API

Tags: excel, vba, api

I'm starting my journey with Excel with a small project.

I would like to add dynamics parameters from my array C2:C50 to my call API in Power Query.

[myExcelArray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyUn7.png)

My Call API look like this : https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest?CMC_PRO_API_KEY=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&symbol=ETH,BTC,...

Could you help me ?

Comment: What does your power query code look like now?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I need 50 reputation points to comment. That's just stupid.

Here's what I did:

1. I made your array a Table, select your table and import the
   data using Power Query (Data, Get Data, From other sources, Table or
   range)
2. Once in PQ, I transposed the table, then merged the columns and then
   drilled down to just get the value of the merged data like
   "BTC,ETH,BNB,ADA,USDT".
3. Now you just make that result an input into your API call and voila

PM me if you need more help.